# Example of a relation that is reflexive but not symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, examples-counterexamples

By definition, $R$, a relation in a set X, is reflexive if and only if $\forall x\in X$, $x\,R\,x$, and $R$ is symmetric if and only if $x\,R\,y\implies y\,R\,x$.

I think $x\,R\,x$ can also be symmetric when I read the definition, but I also feel there's something wrong or missing in my understanding.

Can you give an example of a relation that is reflexive but not symmetric?

Comment: $\leq$, $\geq$, $\subseteq$, ...

Comment: @BrianO The strict variants are not reflexive.

Comment: @Ari Totally spaced out - somehow I translated 'reflexive' to  "transitive". I'll delete that! Thanks.

Comment: Somewhere, there's a list that shows relations can be any combination of reflexive, symmetric and transitive (despite the famous false proof that symmetric + transitive -> reflexive).

Comment: Not taller than.

Comment: I have created a [canonical Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802279/), which is meant to address this question, and others like it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Should we now vote to close the old questions like these as duplicates of the canonical one?

Comment: @Brahadeesh That would be my preference, but I think that it would be an abuse of my power as a moderator to close these questions as duplicate, while funneling views towards a topic which I both created and answered, so I'm not going to do it myself. ;)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thought so, just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 17):

It's important to remember quantifiers. $R$ is symmetric if and only if $x R y \Rightarrow yRx$ **for all** $x,y$. Certainly $x Rx \Rightarrow x R x$, but this does not mean $R$ is symmetric.

An example of a relation that is reflexive but not symmetric is $\leq$. For all $x$, $x \leq x$. However, $x \leq y $ does not imply $ y \leq x$ - for example, $1 \leq 2$, but it's not the case that $2 \leq 1$.

Answer (score 12):

"Knows The Name of" is reflexive but not symmetric.

Everyone knows their own name.

$a \space R \space a$ and $b \space R  \space b$

Alan knows Bob's name:

$a \space R \space b$

Bob does not know Alan's name- he is forgetful.

$Not$ $b \space {R} \space a$

Comment: Not if they have amnesia.

Comment: Huh, who is this?

Comment: https://youtu.be/zr2L_HF9stw?t=23s

Answer (score 4):

A relation is symmetric if $xRy \implies yRx$ for all $x,y$.

You always know that $xRx \implies xRx$, because it is not possible that $xRx$ is true and $xRx$ is false at the same time. This is regardless of whether $R$ is reflexive or not.

There are plenty of examples:

- All ordenings on sets with more than one element, in particular $\leq$ on $\mathbb N, \mathbb Z, \mathbb Q, \mathbb R$.
- $x \mid y$, that is, $x$ divides $y$, on $\mathbb N, \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

> Somewhere, there's a list that shows relations can be any combination of reflexive, symmetric and transitive (despite the famous false proof that symmetric + transitive -> reflexive).  – [barrycarter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2469/barrycarter) [3 hours ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590818/example-of-a-relation-that-is-reflexive-but-not-symmetric#comment3239939_1590818)

Well, I couldn't find one to link to in a few minutes, so let me provide one here.

On the three-element set $\{a, b, c\}$, the following relations are:

- Transitive, symmetric: $R_0 = \emptyset$
- Transitive, not symmetric: $R_1 = \{(a,b)\}$
- Not transitive, not symmetric: $R_2 = \{(a,b), (b,c)\}$
- Not transitive, symmetric: $R_3 = \{(a,b), (b,a), (b,c), (c,b)\}$

None of the relations above are reflexive, but they can all be turned into reflexive relations, without affecting their transitivity or symmetry, by adding $R^* = \{(a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}$ to them.

(In particular, $R_1 \cup R^* = \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b), (c,c)\}$ is a reflexive, non-symmetric relation on the set $\{a, b, c\}$.  Of course, the restriction of this relation to the two-element subset $\{a, b\}$ yields an even simpler example.)

Answer (score 3):

Examples are not that compelling because the conditions are so easy to meet that the general case can be constructed directly.  The ones based on $\geq$ or other (partial) orderings to create asymmetry are misleading because they are transitive, a strong extra condition that is not typical of reflexive asymmetric relations.

General construction: take any asymmetric relation and add all the $xRx$ relations needed to make it reflexive.   Any reflexive asymmetric relation is of that form.

The picture is of any directed graph, that has a loop at every vertex.  To see examples, draw any directed graph, and put a loop at every vertex.

"Has seen" or "has telephoned the house of" are everyday examples.